# Azure AD prevents adding HTTP reply URLs

Tags: azure, http, azure-active-directory

When trying to add a reply URL on the Reply URLs settings screen for Azure AD, we are unable to add a non-HTTPS URL. There are previously-entered URLs that begin with HTTP://, but it won't let a new one be added, saying it must be HTTPS. Since there are some URLs with HTTP entered, it must have been valid at one point.

This is an example screenshot of the Reply URLs screen taken from an Azure AD help page:

[image: Reply URLs settings screen]

The field turns red and refuses to allow an HTTP URL. Is there a setting that can be changed to ease this restriction?

In this case, the URL the login is for is something like http://my-site-dev, and the redirect URL should be the same. The URL is arbitrarily set in my hosts file and bound to localhost, but I need the reply URL to be set in Azure to test authentication.

Comment: You could try editing the "Manifest" directly (should be an option further down) - I just tried this and was able to add an http:// url - haven't tested to see if it actually works.

Comment: The screen shot you have shared it seems very old. Now you can add both `http` and `https`  as reply URL in application registration page and manifest file as well.I have tested [App Registrations](https://imgur.com/a/xPclxAu) and [App Registrations Legacy](https://imgur.com/a/xPclxAu) And there is no other settings for that. You can try on azure portal.

Comment: Is this Azure AD, or Azure AD B2C?

Comment: @HongOoi Its also possible to set `http` on B2C portal. But while you register then you have to set `https` later you can update it to `http`[check here](https://imgur.com/a/07IynPU). If is it `https://b2cdomian.onmicrosoft.com/` in that case `https` is mandatory.

Comment: @mbomb007 By the way, which portal  you are using? I have seen your page is in preview? I haven't seen this before. I am curious a bit!

Comment: The image I used was a sample image taken from an Azure help page. The question I was asking on behalf of someone else, and what I really saw was in your answer. It looked like the 3rd screenshot in your answer.

Comment: @mbomb007 its just the standard azure portal as far as I am aware , however it is a dev/test subscription. maybe this is why it is preview?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn As stated in the question, the screenshot was taken from an AzureAD help page, as I didn't want to expose real information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen shot you have shared I have not seen this window in my side. Now you can add both `http` and `https` as reply URL in application registration page and manifest file as well.

I have tested `App Registrations` and `App Registrations Legacy` And there is no other settings for that. You can try on azure portal in following ways.

**Manifest File:**

[image]

**Reply URLs:**

*App Registrations (Legacy)*

[image]

*App Registrations:*

[image]

**Note:** While you are registering new apps in that time it would encounter you to set `http`. Just put `https` and after app registration update it to `http`

Comment: This was very helpful. I basically see the last screenshot, but if I enter an HTTP reply, it prevents it from saving. Perhaps it's because there is an HTTPS logout URL in the Advanced Settings? I had to change it in the manifest, which did work.

Comment: I've entered my http dev url through the manifest, but I'm still getting the error "AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application".

Comment: Need to have look your context. could you please share some more details.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It was my mistake entering it incorrectly. This works, thank you.

Comment: Works like a charm!